# Where to ask a fictional astronomy question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about planets, eclipses and how a day would work on a moon like Pandora in the movie Avatar, orbiting a massive planet. Where should I post it?

- On Movies & Tv it's obviously off-topic IMO because the answer would be physics-oriented and not about plot or lore or things like that.
- It could fit on world building, but I feel like I would have to spin the question like "In my world, there's a planet that's [...]" since if it's not about building a world it's generally off-topic (*"how does this already existing world work, physics-wise?"* isn't the best question there). But I'd like to have the question based on the available material as much as possible.
- I could also try space or physics since it's hard science, but I don't feel like fictional planets are very on-topic.

Where's the best place for that?

Answer (score 12):

Our [worldbuilding site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions) is just right for this:

> Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a site for designers, writers,
> artists, gamers and enthusiasts to get help creating imaginary worlds.
>
> World building includes geography, culture and creatures for the
> world, not to mention magic and planetary physics, in short,
> everything from the physics underlying your reality to the entire
> universe you want to build.

There are three levels of science tag: "reality-check" for what it says on the tin through "science-based" up to "hard-science" for the equations and cited references.

Be sure to take their [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and read-up in their [help centre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) before asking to ensure that your question is in good shape.

Also, hold in mind that asking questions about third-party works is off-topic, so as long as you make it clear that it's only a world *like Pandora*, not Pandora, then you should be fine.

An associated site is our [writing stack](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions) for more author-specific advice, covering aspects such as structure, presentation and publishing.

Happy worldbuilding.

Comment: Well I'd like to have the question based on the available material as much as possible, such as the relative size of the planet in the sky as seen in the movie for example. I'm not super comfortable with pretending it's about "a world like Pandora" when it's specifically about Pandora.

Answer (score 8):

Questions about fictional planets are ok on the [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) site, as long as the question is about real-world science. Eg, we currently have over 70 questions on the movie [Interstellar](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+interstellar+movie). Sure, some of those are closed, but that's because they lack focus, or don't conform to other site rules, not because they're about a fictional world.

However, questions about fictional scenarios that go beyond real-world science are not welcome. We can't give a physics answer if the story breaks the laws of physics. So (for example) we can't answer questions involving FTL (faster than light) travel. But if the FTL is only part of the story background and irrelevant to the topic of your actual question, then your question should be fine.

Bear in mind that we prefer *conceptual* questions. If your question asks for a specific computation, it is likely to get closed as homework-like. Please see [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) for details.

---

Questions about real-world celestial mechanics are also welcome on the [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) site. We *prefer* questions about real celestial bodies, but if you're just asking about general principles, using a fictional planet as an example, your question should be ok. The homework policy on Astronomy isn't quite as strict as on Physics, and we don't mind questions asking about calculations. However, asking for detailed calculations specifically for the orbit and eclipse cycle of Pandora *might* be pushing it. ;)

Comment: Do you mean that [this question](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-a-wooden-ball-the-size-of-Texas-fell-into-the-ocean/answer/Dave-Consiglio) would be acceptable? How hypothetical is it allowed to be? The starting conditions for [this one](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-99-of-the-earths-crust-became-Uranium-235/answer/Dave-Consiglio) wouldn't be possible to achieve (though it may be possible with an infinite number of universes).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum The wooden ball question would be fine on Physics. To make it acceptable on Astronomy you'd have to modify it a little, eg make it an ice ball, which has a fairly similar mean density. The uranium crust one is a bit problematic. It can't arise naturally, and it'd be hard to construct (and require all the uranium from a vast number of stellar systems). OTOH, we do have questions about extremely low probability scenarios, eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/606390/123208